# How to detect prematurely cut-off speech recording?

Tags: audio-processing, speech

I'm searching for simple method to detect whether the audio recording is prematurely ended in the middle of the pronounciation of a word.

I haven't found any literature on this topic, my idea is to try with ratio of the energy of few frames ath the end and at the start of the recording. This assumes that recording starts with silence and ends somewhere in the middle of the word, having quite higher energy...

Any advice, pointer to literature or better idea ?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you will need a way to detect whether voicing is active, and I think from there it's pretty straightforward to check whether voice is active at the end of the file. Voice activity detection (VAD) is probably a term you *have* come across during your research!